# No modulenames 'requests_oauthlib'

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0

I get:

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests_oauthlib'
```

I am using windows 64 bit python 32 bit.  Any idea why this is happening?

This is installed as per:

```
C:\Users\Chea\zz>pip install requests requests_oauthlib
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\Chea\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: requests_oauthlib in c:\users\Chea\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\Chea\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\Chea\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in c:\users\Chea\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\Chea\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=0.6.2 in c:\users\Chea\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from requests_oauthlib)
```

This is a workaround but hardly addresses root cause: `sys.path.append('PTHONPATHTOSITEPACKAGES')`

Comment: Is the place they installed to definitely in Python's import path?

Comment: @khelwood Is this a bug?  I tried it on my laptop as well and same issue

Comment: Not necessarily. You could have set up your laptop wrongly in the same way as your other computer. For instance, the `pip` you are running might be associated with a different Python install from the `python` that you are running.

Comment: @khelwood Both are 64 bit computers and both are running 32 bit standard python.  IS there a way to address this issue outside of sys.path.append

Comment: Is this your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34051388/windows-pip-installing-libraries-in-wrong-directory

Comment: @khelwood Nope as in I tried to do this and it did not work, I think that module is just weird.