# Pip install installs libraries into different locations

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I have just started using python and I have set up python3 to be installed in C:\Python37 dir. I have added python3 path to environment variables. When I run *python3 -m pip install [package_name]* it installs it in C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages. But when I try to install pylint with *python3 -m pip install pylint* it prints:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pylint in c:\users\radio\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (2.3.1)
```

It's installing it in above mentioned completely different location, and then VS Code complains how pylint is not installed. Why doesn't pip install it in *C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages* where it installs all the other packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you might have multiple python installations on the computer or you are not running CMD with administrator priviledges when using pip.
I would refer you to this thread: [windows pip installing libraries in wrong directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34051388/windows-pip-installing-libraries-in-wrong-directory) which seems to deal with a problem similar to the one you are having.

I would also try checking the environment variables to see the path set for Python if that doesn't work.

Comment: you're absolutely right bro, installing from administrator powershell installs in the correct location