# Windows Sphinx installation failed... what went wrong?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I’m following the instructions in [Installing Sphinx - Windows](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/installation.html#windows).

Python 2.7 has priority in my system path, but Python 3.8 is on my system. I installed Sphinx by typing:

"c:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\pip" install -U sphinx

Pip reported no errors.

Then I entered the command `sphinx-build --version` and got: “ ‘sphinx-build’ is not recognized as an internal or external command,” etc.

I searched the Python38 directory (and children) for sphinx-build. It isn’t there, although C:\Program Files\Python38\Lib\site-packages contains lots of other files named `sphinx*.*`.

Next I searched C:\ for `sphinx-build`. It isn’t anywhere on the disk.

It *appears* that the Sphinx installer ran successfully but silently did something wrong, yielding an incomplete installation. It seems more likely that I did something wrong, but I don’t know what. Any ideas?

Comment: Python 2.x is end of life, so today you should only have Python 3 in your system path.

Comment: Really not relevant. I'm partly responsible for maintaining production applications which are written in Python 2. We have discussed migrating them, but it will take a major commitment of resources. Until that happens, Python 2.7 remains my primary tool for programming.

Comment: If you cannot put Python 3 in path, then you might call `c:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe -m sphinx` instead. Due to Windows UAC, the actual installation folder can vary (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34051388/windows-pip-installing-libraries-in-wrong-directory) mentioned).

Comment: I added Python 3.8 to the path in front of Python 2.7. I had to delete all of the Sphinx files and reinstall, but then the sphinx-build command worked correctly. // This is a workaround, not a fix, because I'll have to change the path again whenever I work on a Python 2.7 program. It makes the problem less urgent and probably easier to solve, though. Thank you.